# Autofixure Fixture.Customize - why do the overloads have different return types?

Tags: c#, autofixture

I'd like to know why it is that the generic `Customize` overload returns `void` and seems to mutate the fixture when the non-generic overload, which takes an instance of a `ICustomization`, returns an `IFixture`?

```
// you cannot set this var, customize returns void
var configuredFixture = fixture.Customize<whatever>(x => x.OmitAutoProperties());
// this is valid
var configuredFixture = fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
```

I ask because I had thought to inline a customization using the fluent style doing something like below, which is of course not valid.

```
var localFixture = fixture
    .Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization())
    .Customize<whatever>(x => x.OmitAutoProperties()));
```

Comment: Because the writer of the 'fixture' class decided they should. fixture is not a default class of hte .NET Framework as far as I can tell. So a link to the documentation might allow us to actually answer this.

Comment: Here's the relevant portion of the source of the `Fixture` class on GitHub (assuming that `fixture` is of type `Fixture`): https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/Fixture.cs#L246-L262

Not sure why `Customize(ICustomization customization)` has `return this` on line 252 but `Customize<T>(Func<ICustomizationComposer<T>, ISpecimenBuilder> composerTransformation)` does not. You could open a pull request or an issue to get it changed?

Comment: @Donut: It looks like this "fixture" class is spelled without capital 'F'. Indeed these code examples look like static method for a Factory Pattern.

Comment: @Christopher `fixture` is the name of the variable he's using here, not necessarily the name of the type. It's not clear from OP's code what the specific type is, but since he's using Autofixture and both methods he's referring to are members of the `Fixture` class, it seemed a reasonable guess.

Comment: Can you think of a way to phrase your question less subjectively? I don't know that any answer other than one by the author of the library will satisfy your query as-is

Comment: well there ya go - an answer from the proverbial horse's mouth :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall answer is: *because I made mistakes*

These two methods are, unfortunately, not particularly related, and you should really think of them as being different, and having two different names, like `Foo<T>`, and `Bar`.

When I wrote those functions, I couldn't think of a better name; hence the unfortunate, but mostly incidental, similarity.

IIRC, I created those two methods at different phases in the development of AutoFixture. AFAIR, `Customize<T>` came first.

After some use of AutoFixture, I realised that it'd be nice with a formal 'module' or 'package' system for AutoFixture, so I added `ICustomization`, and the `Customize` method to go with it.

It was my original intent that one could chain together calls to `Customize`, so I added the [Fluent Interface](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) (i.e. returned the `IFixture` instance) to enable that. The intent was to make it a convenience, but in hindsight, I consider it a mistake. The method *does* mutate the input argument, so that design violates [Command Query Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).

In my defense, though, Fluent Interfaces were all the rage back then...

One really ought to add [an issue](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues) to the AutoFixture repository to remove the return value from `Customize`...

Comment: just goes to show that unless you are able to address the historical progression of some piece of code, the only insight people can get is limited by the assumption that _this is how it's supposed to be_

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark.  The API struck me as incongruous and I was left wondering if things were being mutated in one case but not in the other.  This clears up my confusion perfectly.  I'll see about adding an issue and linking this thread.

Answer (score 0):

It's very common to provide both a generic and a non-generic version of a particular function. When the generic arguments can be inferred unambiguously by the compiler, the type arguments to the `Customize<T>` function don't need to be supplied.

I can't speak to the developer's intent, but I can speak to how the library is providing two different styles of interacting with it.

One approach is through the fluent interface. In a fluent interface, methods almost always return a reference to an instance of the object passed into it (and which it may have mutated). This is the first approach you outlined, `var localFixture = fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());`

The other approach is more of a functional interface. In a functional paradigm, side-effects are a big no-no. In other words, a function that returns the current date shouldn't also mutate or modify anything else external to it. By specifying `void` as the return type for the other `Customize` method, the author of the library is explicit that the effect of the function is to mutate the `fixture` object instance.

A more thorough examination of the library's documentation and/or source would allow you to walk through both methods to discover more about why it's written as it is.

Comment: "I can't speak to the developer's intent" this is why I asked.  I'm aware of everything else you said.

Comment: Maybe email the developer then to get it directly from the source then?

Comment: Sadly that would work but then no one else would benefit from the answer.